# How to save application state in android?

Tags: android, save, state

I have an application with one activity and a lot of fragments. There is one very important fragment and i need save all application state when application's closing down. I need all the data, retrieved from db in this fragment, i need all back stack etc. Files with SP(SharedPreferences) particulary helped me - when i'm restoring my app after it was closed on that fragment, it's opening on that fragment and data's restoring from file, but i'm losing backstack. Help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to save data to be used when re-opened is to use SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean(KEY, value);
editor.commit();
```

To use data later:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean value = preferences.getBoolean(KEY, defaultValue);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I used it, but it didn't solve my problem (in my question SP=SharedPreferences). But thanks for answer!